# Cannot get line break in section heading in jss article. The section headings are centered

Tags: sectioning, line-breaking

I am unable to get line breaks in my section headings - have tried all of the suggestions above.  I am compiling in pdflatex and using the jss format.  The section headings are centered for jss format.  That may be the problem.

Comment: Can you provide us with some form of [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that replicates this result? Also, what format is `jss`? Can you provide a link to the class?

Comment: Just an additional comment: The Journal of Statistical Software requires single line section titles, that is why `jss.cls` is set up like that.

Answer (score 2):

The class uses `\centerline` to centre the titles, so it really doesn't want you to use multi-line titles.

If you must you can do

```
\documentclass{jss}
\begin{document}
\section{zzzz}
xxx
\section[zz zz]{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}c@{}}zz\\zz\end{tabular}}
xxx
\end{document}
```

But the result is

[image]

So using a shorter title might be prefereable.